Weighted average for multiple confusion matrix
I have problem and i have no idea how to resolve it.

I have 4 Confusion Matrixes and i need to calculate for example Matthews Correlation for each CM.
In second step i want calculate BIG KPI result based on 4 results calculated in step no.1

I want calculate it as Weighted Average Result
However if i calculate MCC based on sum of all confusion matrixes events, result is not the same.
Not sure how i can get same results using both ways especially if there will be a case where one confusion matrix result is null (caused by DIV/0 - e.g case where TP/FP/FN are all zero and only TN is available) and then result for weighted average result is even worse.
Is it possible to have same result of KPI using weighted average and KPi calculated on SUM of Confusion matrixes events?
Is there any alternatives for weighted average if i need calculate one number using 4 separate results?
If weighted average is OK, how properly define weights?
